# Rundeck Offline Installation

Tags: rundeck

Is there a way to install rundeck offline using rpm? I installed it through 2 ways but I am having an issue for both.

1) I used yum install on the rundeck rpm but I am unable to find rundeck under /etc or /opt after installation.

```
$ yum install rundeck.rpm

...

Installed:  rundeck-repo.noarch 0:4-0                                                                                                                                                                               Complete!

$ find / -name rundeck
$
```

2) I used an executable war file. This runs rundeck, but I am unable to find an etc folder and unable to find and configure rundeck's web.xml. I am planning to integrate it with AD using the web.xml file.

```
$ java -jar rundeck-3.2.2-20200204.war

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

[2020-03-04 15:05:35.857]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] Starting Rundeck 3.2.2-20200204 (2020-02-10) ...
[2020-03-04 15:05:35.863]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] using rdeck.base config property: /apps/rundeck
[2020-03-04 15:05:35.865]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] Performing rundeck first-run initialization...
[2020-03-04 15:05:35.910]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] Rundeck initialization complete.
[2020-03-04 15:05:35.916]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] loaded configuration: /apps/rundeck/etc/framework.properties
[2020-03-04 15:05:35.959]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] RSS feeds disabled
[2020-03-04 15:05:35.959]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] Using builtin realm authentication
[2020-03-04 15:05:35.959]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] Preauthentication is disabled
[2020-03-04 15:05:36.000]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] Rundeck is ACTIVE: executions can be run.
[2020-03-04 15:05:36.134]  WARN BootStrap --- [           main] [Development Mode] Usage of H2 database is recommended only for development and testing
[2020-03-04 15:05:36.261]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] Rundeck startup finished in 491ms
Grails application running at http://edarck-vccn002.wsgc.com:4440 in environment: production
[2020-03-04 15:05:51.288] DEBUG GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter --- [ qtp31156923-28] Request is to process authentication
[2020-03-04 15:05:51.504] DEBUG GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter --- [ qtp31156923-28] Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@ffcd2057: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: admin,user; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@43458: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.209.145; SessionId: node0cr9j6mc0el7d1mkvw68we3ske0; Granted Authorities: admin, user
$ find / -name web.xml
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install RPM follow these steps:

1) Keep in mind the [minimum](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/install/system-requirements.html) requirements.

2) Download the RPM previously from [here](https://bintray.com/rundeck/rundeck-rpm/download_file?file_path=rundeck-3.2.3.20200221-1.noarch.rpm), and save it on a flash drive.

3) Mount your flash drive in CentOS/RHEL and install the RPM package doing:

```
rpm -i /path/to/undeck-3.2.3.20200221-1.noarch.rpm
```

4) Edit your [/etc/rundeck/rundeck-config.properties](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/config-file-reference.html#rundeck-config-properties) file and [/etc/rundeck/framework.properties](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/config-file-reference.html#framework-properties) accordingly to your network address/setup.

5) Enable Rundeck service doing:

```
systemctl enable rundeckd
```

6) Start Rundeck service doing:

```
systemctil start rundeckd
```

Now, the web.xml file is not relevant anymore to integrate with [LDAP](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#ldap) / [AD](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#active-directory) since Rundeck 3.0.X. You can get the roles directly from your LDAP tree, take a look at [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rundeck-discuss/Wnj0MHsgV1U/JCSJgxm6AAAJ).